# App fails to build for WP8 under PGB, but builds to Android without problems

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I have forked [WildBeast's ScannerPlugin demo](https://github.com/trejder/BarcodeDemo) and built it in my PGB. All is fine. Builds perfectly for both Android and WP8. I have then built [my own project](https://github.com/trejder/phonegap-2d-code-reader) basing on this demo, did a lot of changes and again built it through PGB.

PhoneGap Build is constantly refusing to build to Windows Phone 8 platform with following error (from log):

```
C:\project\App.xaml(1,1,1,1): error : x:Class="com.trejder.phonegap.2dcodereader.App" is not valid. 'com.trejder.phonegap.2dcodereader.App' is not a valid fully qualified class name. [C:\project\_2DCodeReader.csproj]
C:\project\MainPage.xaml(1,1,1,1): error : x:Class="com.trejder.phonegap.2dcodereader.MainPage" is not valid. 'com.trejder.phonegap.2dcodereader.MainPage' is not a valid fully qualified class name. [C:\project\_2DCodeReader.csproj]
```

Can someone spare few minutes to investigate and tell me, what is going on? There is no `MainPage` anywhere within my source code, so I don't know, what PGB reffers to?

Application build to Android and works there as a charm. There are also no errors and problems, when testing it locally through Ripple.

This is something new for me.  Up until know, all my apps built via PhoneGap Build were either building fine to all platforms or not building at all.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that either PhoneGap Build (when building for WP8) or Windows Phone specification itself does not allow using **numbers** in application ID (Android does).

Changing `com.trejder.phonegap.2dcodereader` to `com.trejder.phonegap.barcodereader` fixed the problem in my case. Application now builds without any problems to all platforms in PGB.